# Slow SQL Server CLR aggregates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate, sqlclr

I've always found the lack of a built-in aggregate function that just strings together values using some user defined separator, frustrating.

The closest thing I know of is the XML hack:

```
select s.string as [text()] 
from strings s 
for xml path('')
```

But in my opinion that's a very strange way of doing it and you still have to handle the case with trailing or leading separator junk. So, I thought I'd write a CLR aggregate:

```
select dbo.Fold(s.string, ', ') 
from strings s
```

That's kind of nice. Except this thing doesn't perform very well when the number of rows reaches 5000. I don't really expect to run it against that much data but to my surprise the performance of the aggregate degrades rather rapidly as the data set grows. I didn't understand why at first, then I realized that the way the UDF is handled in SQL Server is the problem.

I'm using an UDF with a `StringBuilder` class, because of this I have to implement `IBinarySerialize`. But for reasons I do not understand SQL Server is calling the Write/Read pair between each iteration of `Accumulate`. Obviously this creates a performance problem when the string gets big. Is there anyway to avoid this costly serialization?

FYI, the XML hack are orders of magnitudes faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is implementing the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT

See these for inspiration...

- An answer on [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005/2149432#2149432)
- ["GROUP_CONCAT string aggregate for SQL Server" on codeplex](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)

Personally, I use the XML trick.

Comment: The XML trick appears to be the right choice in this matter, it's just a horrible syntax. The group_concat stuff maintains a frequency table while running the aggregate, I'm guessing it performance is just as bad but it's an interesting approach.